# Making new variable instead of correcting for temporal autocorrelation in a GLMM. Is it a valid alternative?

Tags: regression, logistic, autocorrelation, predictor

I am doing some forest disturbance research, in which the aim is to predict the probabilities of wind damage occurrence in forest stands of different site (altitude, slope steepness) and stand properties (age, timber volume).
I am using a logistic regression (because of the binomial response variable: 0-1) with the R package "lme4".

My data set looks like this (several thousand forest stands in the full data set):

```
stand_id    year    damage  altitude    slope   age volume  occurrence
123 2001    0   900 15  100 235 0
123 2002    0   900 15  101 242 0
123 2003    0   900 15  102 249 0
123 2004    3.6 900 15  103 256 1
123 2005    0   900 15  104 259.4   0
123 2006    2.1 900 15  105 266.4   1
123 2007    1.8 900 15  106 271.3   1
123 2008    0   900 15  107 276.5   0
123 2009    0   900 15  108 283.5   0
123 2010    0   900 15  109 290.5   0
124 2001    0   1100    10  80  172 0
124 2002    0   1100    10  81  181 0
124 2003    6.2 1100    10  82  190 1
124 2004    8.9 1100    10  83  192.8   1
124 2005    2.4 1100    10  84  192.9   1
124 2006    0   1100    10  85  199.5   0
124 2007    0   1100    10  86  208.5   0
124 2008    5.5 1100    10  87  217.5   1
124 2009    2.4 1100    10  88  221 1
124 2010    0   1100    10  89  227.6   0
```

.
.
.

If damage is bigger than 0, the response variable (occurrence) has a value of 1, otherwise 0.
The model would be: occurrence ~ altitude + slope + age + volume

As you can see, there are measurements in all years for a 10-year period in all of the stands.
Since we have more than one measurements for the same forest stand, a random effect (of forest stand) has to be added to the model, which will be the factor "stand_id".
Regard to my understanding of Statistics, spatial autocorrelation is not a problem anymore, but temporal autocorrelation of the (residuals of the) response variable is still something needs to be dealt with. I have checked the autocorrelation function (acf) of it, and it is apparent in the first following year (acf value is ~ 0.1), then it dies off.

Many experts advise to model the temporal autocorrelation structure and use it as a correction for the previously fitted (logistic regression) model.
I find this a bit tedious and overcomplicated (also cannot do simply in lme4), therefore my question would be:

Is it a valid alternative if I make a new predictor variable that is the damage of the previous year (because of the acf) and use it in the model, as well?
To make it more clear, here is the new data set (last column is added):

```
stand_id year damage  altitude slope    age   volume occurrence dmg_prev
123 2001    0   900 15  100 235 0   0
123 2002    0   900 15  101 242 0   0
123 2003    0   900 15  102 249 0   0
123 2004    3.6 900 15  103 256 1   0
123 2005    0   900 15  104 259.4   0   3.6
123 2006    2.1 900 15  105 266.4   1   0
123 2007    1.8 900 15  106 271.3   1   2.1
123 2008    0   900 15  107 276.5   0   1.8
123 2009    0   900 15  108 283.5   0   0
123 2010    0   900 15  109 290.5   0   0
124 2001    0   1100    10  80  172 0   0
124 2002    0   1100    10  81  181 0   0
124 2003    6.2 1100    10  82  190 1   0
124 2004    8.9 1100    10  83  192.8   1   6.2
124 2005    2.4 1100    10  84  192.9   1   8.9
124 2006    0   1100    10  85  199.5   0   2.4
124 2007    0   1100    10  86  208.5   0   0
124 2008    5.5 1100    10  87  217.5   1   0
124 2009    2.4 1100    10  88  221 1   5.5
124 2010    0   1100    10  89  227.6   0   2.4
```

.
.
.

Running the model with this new variable (dmg_prev), it also turns out to be significant, and if I am right, it carries the information on the temporal autocorrelation, as well.
So no additional correction is needed anymore.
Could someone verify this?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!